# Java Component Placing

Tags: java, components, jlabel

Why is the grass image not at the top of the JFrame?  And why isn't the character starting at location 200, 200.  He only moves once I click a key.  Can anybody explain to me why I am having these issues?

[image]

Frame:

```
package frame;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.*;

import input.Key;
import character.Character;

public class Frame {
public static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
public static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
public static JPanel minimap = new JPanel();
public static JLabel map = new JLabel();

private static int width = 400;
private static int height = 400;

public static void create() {
    Frame f = new Frame();
    f.loadResources();
    f.init();
}

private void loadResources() {
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
            getClass().getResource("map.png"));
    ImageIcon mapImg = new ImageIcon(image);
    map.setIcon(mapImg);

    panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    panel.add(map);
    Character.createCharacter();
    panel.setComponentZOrder(Character.character, 0);
    frame.add(panel);

}

private void init() {
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
            getClass().getResource("icon.png"));

    frame.setIconImage(image);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle("Infested");

    frame.addKeyListener(new Key());
}
}
```

Character loading:

```
    public static void createCharacter() {
    speed = 3;
    character.setIcon(CharacterSheet.downRightLeg);
    Frame.panel.add(character);
    px = 200;
    py = 200;
    character.setLocation(px, py);
    characterObj = new Rectangle(charX, charY, 56, 63);
}
```

Comment: some component have a different color and they are placed at the top of each other composed into the card layout and after that spread to the borders.

Comment: Check this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VE7ezYCTPe4

Comment: I'm not using a tutorial.  I already have the walking aspect of my game done, this is just one thing I'm stuck on.

Comment: Although you don't show us what your character object actually is, it looks like you are trying to make a game with GUI components and you can't do that with Swing. Maybe you should use a tutorial. If you continue trying to do what it looks like you are doing, this will not be the only problem like this you run in to. Problems like this will be everywhere.